# Snap Chat IE 10

Tags: chat, ie10

I have an application written in angular 2. I have snap chat working with latest  firefox, chrome, ie 11. With ie 10, I get cors exceptions. I tried Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites > Added my domain and the live agent domain. Anybody else experiencing ie10 issues?

Comment: YES... Not with Snap Chat, but with other services. What I have done is make the client call a SF service that calls out to the external app. Kind of a middle-man web service, strictly because of IE10. I would love to find another way though.